# Which boost macro would allow me to do insert variable number of statements in the program

Tags: c, boost, macros, boost-preprocessor

Suppose I want to achieve the following **example** effect :

```
if (i) j--;
```

Now I want to insert that line in my program as many times as I want repeatedly.  If I wanted to insert that statement 1000 times then I'd have to copy paste it manually.

The purpose is to *insert statements* in the program and not just achieve the same logical behaviour.

I would like to use a macro that given a statement and an `n` inserts the statement `n` times in the program. I think this is possible using some Boost library macro. But I have never used Boost and I don't know which one should I use. Also I am restricted to **C** and not C++, but I believe that this boost macro should work in **C** as well.

I want to what to use and how to use it to achieve this effect

Comment: It sounds like you want something like `BOOST_PP_REPEAT` from [Boost.Preprocessor](http://www.boost.org/libs/preprocessor/), but I'm not too sure about using it without a C++ compiler...

Comment: Boost.Preprocessor works with C as well as C++ -- it uses the preprocessor rather than relying on anything specific to C++.

Comment: What is wrong with a for loop?

Comment: @flolo : Maybe he wants compile-time loop unrolling.

Comment: @ildjarn: Indeed that would be scenario where it can be used for. But usually the compiler is better in guessing when unrolling is it worth and when not.

Comment: The intention of the BOOST_PP_REPEAT was for template metaprograming. There it actually makes sense, but as there are no templates in C, I would consider it an anti pattern. If I dont hear any other good reason for using it I would very strongly discourage its usage in this way.

Comment: @flolo yes I **think** what I want to do is compile-time loop unrolling. SImply because I am writing a benchmark that depends on the number of lines of code executed and not on the number of instructions executed. More specifically I wanted a program that would cause a lot of jumps ( tens of thousands) but to different jump locations

Comment: @AnkurVj: Benchmark depending on loc is very unlikely making sense. The reason is because you could write 100 lines of code also in a single line (just by removing the newlines). I dont know the reason you want to generate or how you make it, but you have to be there really carefull (also consider loc before or after preprocess).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are looking for [BOOST_PP_REPEAT](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/libs/preprocessor/doc/ref/repeat.html).

Comment: WIll I have to download the whole boost library to use this feature. Could I download some one .h file which would be sufficient ?

Comment: @AnkurVj: Download - yes, build - no. This is header-only library. You can even use BCP tool to extract a specific library, see http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_41_0/tools/bcp/bcp.html

Comment: @AnkurVj: This is preprocessor, so you most likely can get it to work if it doesn't.